# Comparing large sets of integers individually versus array

Tags: swift

Suppose an object has hundreds of integer instance properties. Half are "initial" values and the other half are "current" values.

```
let initial1 = 0
let initial2 = 9
var current1 = 0
var current2 = 10
...
```

And at some point I need to check if there are any changes in any of these values. Would creating two arrays and comparing them...

```
let initial = [initial1, initial2, ...]
let current = [current1, current2, ...]

if initial != current {
    // do something
}
```

...consume more memory (because they are value types) than simply comparing the instance properties themselves?

```
if initial1 != current1 || initial2 != current2 ... {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Is the count of both arrays the same?

Comment: @Adrian yes they're effectively mirrors of each other

Comment: Perhaps forming an immutable array of value types doesn’t make any copies?

Comment: But in any case the idea that you would need to run through these properties separately is a bad smell. Since you know you will be maintaining this info in pairs they should have been pairs all along.

Comment: Off topic but shouldn’t initial1, initial2 and so on be `let` declared?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no, you're right, they should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would generally require more memory to make a copy of the properties. Also, a struct with many properties does not have the kind of copy-on-write benefits that an Array does. (Copy-on-write is not something you get for free in Swift. It's something that has to be implemented in the data type, and Array implements it.)

I would be very tempted to use a Dictionary as your storage here, rather than hundreds of properties. Dictionaries also have copy-on-write, so if there are many copies of the initial state, you could save some copies there. (I'm assuming they're not really "initial1" and "initial2". If they have a clear order and indexing, then an Array would be correct choice.) I typically have to tell people to use structs instead of Dictionaries, but it's possible this would be an exception. (I'm interested why there are so many integer properties, though.)

I'd also look at `@dynamicMemberLookup`, which might simplify your life significantly.

Note that if these are "initial" and "current" I would definitely split them into two objects rather than merging them with parallel properties. It should be `obj.current.property` rather than `obj.currentProperty` IMO. That would preserve your ability to do `obj.current != obj.initial` without having to make a massive copy.

Comment: Splitting them into two objects, you mean two dictionaries?

Comment: @bsod two Dictionaries or two wrappers that you build around Dictionaries, or two objects that implement their storage in another way. The point being that data be split, regardless of the implementation.